# How to rewrite url while keeping additional parameters in .htaccess file?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the standard htaccess which just catches all and puts it into one url parameter which is later processed in code...

```
RewriteRule ^config/ - [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I use "pretty" url params like

```
/some/route/param1/value1/param2/value2
```

but now I need an ability to add "regular" url params like

```
/some/route/param1/value1?param2=value2&param3=value3 etc
```

I tried adding

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?(.*)$ index.php?q=$1&p=$2 [L,QSA]
```

before the existing rule, but it won't work properly (and I suspect it would only work with one parameter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^?]+)\?(.*)$ index.php?q=$1&p=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved it... The first part of my query was "eating up" the question mark :)  
btw. changing the redirection url part to index.php?q=$1&$2 also allowed the code to 'naturally' process all the _GET parameters.